# Cannot resolve scoped service 'Application.Interfaces.FacadPattern.IStatisticsFacad' from root provider in .net core5

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing Store application with Pro ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. The example is made in ASP.NET Core 5.0.

I get this error while trying to run the program:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Application.Interfaces.FacadPattern.IStatisticsFacad' from root provider

In this file I use `IStatisticsFacad` for saving data in the database:

```
namespace Application.Interfaces.FacadPattern
{
    public interface IStatisticsFacad
    {
        AddStatesticsService AddStatesticsService { get; }
        AddStUserService AddStUserService { get; }
        AddStatesticsDetailService AddStatesticsDetailService { get; }
    }
}
```

and this is facad class

```
 public class StatisticsFacad: IStatisticsFacad
    {
        private readonly IDataBaseContext _context;
        public StatisticsFacad(IDataBaseContext context
            )
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        private AddStatesticsService _AddStatesticsService;
        public AddStatesticsService AddStatesticsService
        {
            get
            {
                return _AddStatesticsService = _AddStatesticsService ?? new AddStatesticsService(_context);
            }
        }

        private AddStUserService _AddStUserService;
        public AddStUserService AddStUserService
        {
            get
            {
                return _AddStUserService = _AddStUserService ?? new AddStUserService(_context);
            }
        }

        private AddStatesticsDetailService _AddStatesticsDetailService;
        public AddStatesticsDetailService AddStatesticsDetailService
        {
            get
            {
                return _AddStatesticsDetailService = _AddStatesticsDetailService ?? new AddStatesticsDetailService(_context);
            }
        }

    }
```

Use in this file ad add in startup file

```
public class ApplicationVariable
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private static int TimeOut = 5;
    private readonly IStatisticsFacad _statisticFacad;

    public ApplicationVariable(RequestDelegate next, IStatisticsFacad statisticFacad)
    {
        _next = next;
        _statisticFacad = statisticFacad;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string UserAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        string refer = httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

        if (UserAgent == null)
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);

        if (Check(httpContext))
        {
            string rndkey = (new Random().Next(1000, 1000000)).ToString() + "-" + (new Random().Next(10000, 10000000) * DateTime.Now.Millisecond).ToString();
            StOnline.set(new On() { key = rndkey, time = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TimeOut) });

            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("OnlineUser", rndkey, new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TimeOut)
            });
            httpContext.Session.SetString("OnlineUser", rndkey);

            var q = _statisticFacad.AddStatesticsService.Execute().IsSuccess;

DateTime.Now.Date).SingleOrDefault();
            var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
            UAParser.ClientInfo UserInfo = uaParser.Parse(UserAgent);

            if (q)
            {
                StUserDto stUser = new StUserDto()
                {
                    OS = UserInfo.OS.Family,
                    Browser = UserInfo.UA.Family,
                    KeyId = rndkey
                };

                var t = _statisticFacad.AddStUserService.Execute(stUser).IsSuccess;

                var IpAdd = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() != null ?
                     httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() : 
                     httpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString();

                string Contry1 = new GetLocation().Get(IpAdd).country;

                StStatDto stDetail = new StStatDto()
                    {
                        CountryName = Contry1,
                        Ip = IpAdd,
                        Refferer = httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString(),
                        Url = httpContext.Request.Host + "/" + httpContext.Request.Path,
                        Key = rndkey,
                    };

                var sd = _statisticFacad.AddStatesticsDetailService.Execute(stDetail).IsSuccess;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string key = GetKey(httpContext);
            StOnline.Update(key, TimeOut);
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("OnlineUser", new CookieOptions
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TimeOut)
            });
            httpContext.Session.Remove("OnlineUser");
            httpContext.Session.SetString("OnlineUser", key);
        }

        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}
```

and startup file

```
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IDataBaseContext, DataBaseContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRecaptchaExtension, RecaptchaExtension>();
            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddScoped<IStatisticsFacad, StatisticsFacad>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataBaseContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityError>()
            .AddPasswordValidator<MyPasswordValidator>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddFluentValidation();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMiddleware<ApplicationVariable>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show how `StatisticsFacad` class is defined. You can remove all the code, but we need to see the class constructor. You are probably trying to inject something in to that class that isn't in the pipeline.

Comment: update and add StatisticsFacad class